# How to create query to get data from the given month?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I must to get all data from my database with using `typeorm` but only this data which are from a given month.

in my db:

```
date-service: 2020-10-25
```

i try to create a query in this way but it return me all datas but i need only from the given month which i provide like a full date, so eq. if I provide `2020-09-10` then i need to get all data from `9`th month.

my query:

```
const data = await this.conn.getRepository(Order).createQueryBuilder("order").getRawMany();
```

how to create a query to get data only from given month?

thanks for any answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem. You can provide a range of date to the query like start and end date of the month which you extract from the given date using moment, date-fns, etc

i usually use **moment.js** when dealing with dates it great.  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

```
let date = 2020-09-10;

const data = await this.conn.getRepository(Order)
    .createQueryBuilder("order")
    .where('date-service >= :after', { after: moment(date).startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') })
    .andWhere('date-service < :before', { before:  moment(date).endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') })
    .getRawMany();
```